# Problemas ao gerar token de acesso do OAuth com HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, json, web-service, oauth2

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição para um webservice que usa o OAuth, para gerar um token de acesso. Porém apesar de a requisição retornar o código Http 200, o json aparece apenas como **{"errors":{"internal":["500"]}}**, abaixo o código:

OBS: Fiz o mesmo procedimento pelo terminal usando curl e os dados foram gerados normalmente.

```
URL url = new URL( "https://api.myapi.com.br/api/oauth/token" );

HttpURLConnection huc = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();

huc.setRequestMethod( "POST" );

huc.setRequestProperty( "grant_type", "client_credentials" );
huc.setRequestProperty( "client_id", CLIENT_ID );
huc.setRequestProperty( "client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET );        

if ( huc.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK )
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( huc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" ) );

    while ( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null )
    {
        content.append( line ); 
    }

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject( content.toString() );

    System.out.println( json );
}
```

Comment: Sua classe CorsFilter implements Filter; Aplica AllowOrigins para ver se vai.

Comment: O Serviço de Auth esta esperando um Json, ou um form-enconde
huc.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: o Auth geralmente espera uma url de callback, e seu content type é Content-Type: application/json ou seja ele espera um objeto. Ele espera essas propriedade "grant_type": "authorization_code",
  "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
  "client_secret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
  "code": "AUTHORIZATION_CODE",
  "redirect_uri": https://YOUR_APP/callback

Comment: Olá @alxwca. Tentei realizar os ajustes sugeridos e mesmo assim o problema persistiu. Montei a URL que gera o HttpURLConnection manualmente. E após executar o código o json retornou corretamente.

**sbUrl.append( "https://api.myapi.com.br/api/oauth/token?" )
             .append( "grant_type=" ).append( "client_credentials" )
             .append( "&" ).append( "client_id=" ).append( CLIENT_ID )
             .append( "&" ).append( "client_secret=" ).append( CLIENT_SECRET );**

 Porém eu realmente gostaria que funcionasse da maneira padronizada, usando os métodos da classe.

Comment: Seu código  faz uma solicitação para o servidor de autorização no formato application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Exato, fiz conforme tu havia sugerido, coloquei **.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );**

Comment: huc.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "*/*" );

Comment: adiciona o comment acima ao código, debuga. e posta aqui seu request.

Comment: Se eu entendi corretamente, segue abaixo o solicitado.

Comment: requests
keys=(String[])(length=8) 
[0] = (String) "Content-Type" 
[1] = (String) "Accept" 
[2] = (String) "grant_type" 
[3] = (String) "client_id" 
[4] = (String) "client_secret" 
[5] = () null 
[6] = () null 
[7] = () null 
values = (String[]) #1055(length=8) 
[0] = (String) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
[1] = (String) "/" 
[2] = (String) "client_credentials" 
[3] = (String) "74f092bb7c941c92847b290375db959b19ca07ae12661fc3f25d5cc48ec71c4b" 
[4] = (String) "0b4324d418045340601dee2c47b75fbcce57757181fbafa98f2067fca29668b2" 
[5] = () null 
[6] = () null 
[7] = () null

Comment: huc.setDoOutput(true);
huc.setDoInput(true);

Se não funcionar tem que ver como ta o seu endpoit, seu servidor auth, Base64Enconding. Mas acho que esses dois vai resolver.

Answer (score -1):

Com é application/x-www-form-urlencoded você vai ter que enviar desta forma:

```
 String params = "gran_type="+client_credentials+"&client_id="+CLIENT_ID+"&client_secret="+client_secret;
        byte[] post = params.getBytes( StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        URL url = new URL(URLEncoder.encode("https://api.myapi.com.br/api/oauth/token?", "ISO-8859-1"));
        HttpsURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setDoInput(true);
        http.setFollowRedirects(false);
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        http.setRequestProperty("charset", "ISO-8859-1");
        http.setUseCaches(false);

        try(DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(http.getOutputStream())){
            output.write(post);
        }
```

Comment: As vezes precisa da output.close() pra ele enviar.

Comment: E seu servidor OAuth pode esta esperando  um "GET", você muda de "POST" para "GET".